# Async/Await + Ajax .done: Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

Sorry if this is extremely simple, I can't get my head around it. I've seen similar questions but nothing which gets to the heart of my problem, I think. I have a simple async function:

```
async function isOpen() {

    var open;

    var data = $.ajax({
      //Working code here
    });

    data.done(function(dat) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(dat);
        var msg = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            let closingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].close);
            let openingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].open);

            if (closingDate > Date.now() && openingDate < Date.now()) {
                open = true;
            } else {
                open = false;
            }
        }
    });

    return open;
}
```

I know that this code is all working - using console.log I have seen that open is always successfully assigned to true or false. So I call this async function from another async function:

```
async function testFunction(){

    const open1 = await isOpen();
    //More code here...

}
```

But `open1` (in `testFunction`) is always undefined - even though I use `await`.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: is open also true or false if you console.log it directly before returning it? And is it still undefined if you set var open = null; at the begining?

Comment: you `return open;` before the ajax will run

Comment: Also, the for loop will overwrite the result of `open`, you may break the loop once your assign a value to open.

Comment: Use `const dat = await data` followed by your code instead of using the `data.done()` callback. (Assuming you use jQuery 3).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
async function isOpen() {

    var open;

    var data = await $.ajax({
      //Working code here
    });

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var msg = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        let closingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].close);
        let openingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].open);

        if (closingDate > Date.now() && openingDate < Date.now()) {
            open = true;
        } else {
            open = false;
        }
    }
    return open;
}
```

of course, the value of `open` will be determined by the last `obj[i]`

So you want

```
async function isOpen() {
    const data = await $.ajax({
      //Working code here
    });
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    let msg = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        const closingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].close);
        const openingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].open);

        if (closingDate > Date.now() && openingDate < Date.now()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or even

```
async function isOpen() {
    const data = await $.ajax({
      //Working code here
    });

    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    let msg = "";
    return obj.some(({open, close}) => {
        const closingDate = Date.parse(close);
        const openingDate = Date.parse(open);
        const now = Date.now();
        return closingDate > now && openingDate < now();
    });
}
```

Comment: `msg` can be removed too.

Comment: Depending on the `dataType` you wouldn't even need to parse the data if it's set to "JSON".

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal - yeah I know - but not going to do everything :p

Comment: @ikhvjs - I doubt anyone uses jquery that old

Comment: @Andy - not my call ... who knows what `//Working code here` even does

Comment: @bravo, it wasn't a comment about your code. I was just pointing something out.

Comment: @Bravo Just pointed it out 'cause you removed `open`, thought `msg` could go out too. Great answer nonetheless :)

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal - I understand, I removed open because I knew what it was there for, no idea why msg is there :p

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are using a callback for ajax request and not waiting for ajax request to complete, which is going to set `open` in `isOpen`. You can return a Promise to resolve this,

```
function isOpen() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var open;

    var data = $.ajax({
      //Working code here
    });

    data.done(function(dat) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(dat);
        var msg = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            let closingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].close);
            let openingDate = Date.parse(obj[i].open);

            if (closingDate > Date.now() && openingDate < Date.now()) {
                open = true;
            } else {
                open = false;
            }
        }
       resolve(open);
    });

  }
}
```

Note: For the above code, you need to handle the logic for errors in the callback, using `reject` otherwise it will hang forever.